# Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/gitlab-ce_12.2.0-ce.0_amd64.deb

Tags: 18.04

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gitlab-ce
1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/680 MB of archives.
After this operation, 145 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 319765 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gitlab-ce_12.2.0-ce.0_amd64.deb ...
gitlab preinstall: It seems you are upgrading from 11.x version series
gitlab preinstall: to 12.x series. It is recommended to upgrade
gitlab preinstall: to the last minor version in a major version series first before
gitlab preinstall: jumping to the next major version.
gitlab preinstall: Please follow the upgrade documentation at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/policy/maintenance.html#upgrade-recommendations
gitlab preinstall: and upgrade to 11.11 first.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gitlab-ce_12.2.0-ce.0_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new gitlab-ce package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gitlab-ce_12.2.0-ce.0_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is self-explanatory.  Upgrade your instance to Gitlab CE 11.11 first.  Then upgrade to 12 series.

Start by installing it:

```
sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce=11.11.8-ce.0
```

This is the latest 11.11 release version.  THEN, once you've upgrade to this normally

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and everything works, upgrade to version 12:

Comment: Just went to this situation with my server. Ended with `sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce=11.11.8-ce.0` as it is more convenient. And then upgraded to 12.2 with usual `sudo apt upgrade`.